# Java, start a screen capture lower than the panel

Tags: java, swing, panel, screenshot

So I am trying to get a screen shot of my panel and the code below does perfect. I want to lower the starting point of the screenshot by like 200 pixels. If I do size.height-200 it raises the bottom . I will need to do that in the future but how do I lower the top too? Or will I need to do a different method?

```
System.out.println("Trying to screenshot");
                    Dimension size = getSize ();
                    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage (size.width, size.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
                    Graphics g = img.getGraphics ();
                    paint (g);
                    g.dispose ();
                    try
                    {
                        ImageIO.write (img, "png", new File ("screenshot1.png"));
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace ();
                    }
```

Comment: Don't use `paint` directly when trying to "capture" components, instead use `printAll`, amongst other things, it disables the double buffering...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to draw a component with an offset? If yes, then AffineTransformation is your friend. Try calling

```
    Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
    g.transform(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(0, -200));
    paint(g);
    g.dispose();
```

Comment: It says I have to add a cast to 'g' but when I do it just gives another error.

Comment: Sorry -- I hadn't noticed you had only a Graphics instance, not a Graphics2D. Generally you are better off using the latter, the Graphics without the 2D is old and limited. I updated the answer.

Comment: Would you need to translate +200 to move down and reduce the height of the output image by 200...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Screen Image](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) class. It allows you to specify a Rectangle when creating an image of the panel.

If you don't want to use the class, then take at look at the code. For your requirement the key is to translate the graphics before you do the painting.